# Invoke ls command in bash script and get all the results

Tags: bash, shell, ls

I'd like to sort a directory with oldest files first, 1 file per line

The command ls can easily give me that

```
[toto@damageinc ~]# ls -drt1 test_dir/*.txt
test_dir/oldest_file.txt
test_dir/mid_file.txt
test_dir/newest_file.txt
```

But I can't manage to put that in a script

Either this :

```
[toto@damageinc ~]# cat test1.sh
#!/bin/bash
ls -drt1 $1
```

Or that :

```
[toto@damageinc ~]# cat test2.sh
#!/bin/bash
IFS=$'\n'
array=($(ls -drt1 $1))
for elt in ${array[*]}
do
    echo $elt
done
```

Give me only one result :

```
[toto@damageinc ~]# sh test1.sh test_dir/*.txt
test_dir/mid_file.txt

[toto@damageinc ~]# sh test2.sh test_dir/*.txt
test_dir/mid_file.txt
```

What am I doing wrong ? Is there a more "powerfull" way without using ls ?
Thanks !

Comment: Try `echo $1` in your script and see what you get.

Comment: omg. Thanks a lot !